# R, extrapolate average scores from graph

Tags: r

I have a graph like this:
[image]

With data that created it like this:

```
test<-structure(list(study_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 94, 
94, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 
105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 117, 117, 117, 
117, 117, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 125, 
125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 131, 131, 131, 131, 
131, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 
154, 154, 154, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 
161, 161, 161, 161, 161, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 166, 166, 166, 
166, 166, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 172, 
172, 172, 172, 172, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 179, 179, 179, 179, 
179, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 
185, 185, 185, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 194, 194, 194, 194, 194, 195, 195, 195, 
195, 195, 197, 197, 197, 197, 197, 199, 199, 199, 199, 199, 203, 
203, 203, 203, 203, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 210, 210, 210, 210, 
210, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 217, 217, 
217, 217, 217, 221, 221, 221, 221, 221, 223, 223, 223, 223, 223, 
227, 227, 227, 227, 227, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 229, 229, 229, 
229, 229, 239, 239, 239, 239, 239, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 253, 
253, 253, 253, 253, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 257, 257, 257, 257, 
257, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 272, 272, 
272, 272, 272, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 277, 277, 277, 277, 277, 
278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 288, 288, 288, 
288, 288, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 291, 291, 291, 291, 291, 292, 
292, 292, 292, 292, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 295, 295, 295, 295, 
295, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 303, 303, 303, 303, 303, 
305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 306, 306, 306, 306, 306, 307, 307, 307, 
307, 307, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 313, 313, 313, 313, 313, 315, 
315, 315, 315, 315, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 320, 320, 320, 320, 
320, 324, 324, 324, 324, 324, 331, 331, 331, 331, 331, 336, 336, 
336, 336, 336, 337, 337, 337, 337, 337, 348, 348, 348, 348, 348, 
349, 349, 349, 349, 349, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 353, 353, 353, 
353, 353, 367, 367, 367, 367, 367, 373, 373, 373, 373, 373, 382, 
382, 382, 382, 382, 387, 387, 387, 387, 387, 388, 388, 388, 388, 
388, 389, 389, 389, 389, 389, 392, 392, 392, 392, 392, 398, 398, 
398, 398, 398, 401, 401, 401, 401, 401, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 
404, 404, 404, 404, 404, 405, 405, 405, 405, 405, 410, 410, 410, 
410, 410, 411, 411, 411, 411, 411, 412, 412, 412, 412, 412, 413, 
413, 413, 413, 413, 414, 414, 414, 414, 414, 415, 415, 415, 415, 
415, 420, 420, 420, 420, 420, 428, 428, 428, 428, 428, 431, 431, 
431, 431, 431, 433, 433, 433, 433, 433, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 
436, 436, 436, 436, 436), Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 7, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 5, 8, NA, NA, 7, 8, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2, 8, 8, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0, 9, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 5, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 2, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 3, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 
    5, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 3, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 7, 8, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
    2, 4, 4, NA, NA), TimeBetweenScans = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    316, NA, NA, NA, NA, 113, 139, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 335, 660, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 104, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30, 84, 467, 
    826, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 643, 1794, NA, NA, NA, 404, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40, 
    221, 394, NA, NA, 171, 320, NA, NA, NA, 51, 227, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 449, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 56, NA, NA, NA, NA, 104, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 79, 989, 1097, NA, NA, 116, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 39, 411, NA, NA, NA, 1193, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 142, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 106, 216, 266, 497, 575, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 221, 474, 
    796, NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, NA, NA, 87, 1565, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 36, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 207, 
    529, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 125, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    137, 372, 941, 1102, 1225, 927, 1006, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 63, 429, 533, 567, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 156, 
    447, 470, 1204, 1266, 32, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 411, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA, NA, 160, NA, NA, NA, NA, 166, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 459, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 212, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, 
    313, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 312, 530, 783, 1574, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1627, 1706, NA, NA, NA, 354, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 33, NA, NA, NA, NA, 62, 130, NA, NA, NA, 
    1416, NA, NA, NA, NA, 121, NA, NA, NA, NA, 842, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 24, 64, 82, 122, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 250, NA, NA, NA, NA, 174, 300, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 216, 264, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 214, 268, 388, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    149, 382, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 91, 188, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 72, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 38, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13, 138, NA, NA, NA, 42, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 771, 1200, 1512, NA, NA, 113, 166, 180, NA, NA, 
    122, 475, 640, NA, NA), Groups = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, 
    NA, "One", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, "Two", 
    "Two", NA, NA, NA, "Zero", "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, "One", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Zero", "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", "Zero", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "One", "One", 
    "One", "One", "One", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "One", 
    "One", "One", "One", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, "One", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, "Two", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", "One", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", "Two", NA, NA, 
    "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", "Two", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Zero", "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Zero", "Two", NA, NA, NA, "Zero", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Two", 
    "Two", "Two", NA, NA, "One", "One", "One", NA, NA, "Two", 
    "Two", "Two", NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -630L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(study_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Score = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), TimeBetweenScans = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Groups = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

And Code that created the graph like this:  I grouped the study id's so that a dotted line was drawn connecting all the scores from each individual patient.  So each line is one person.

```
test%>%ggplot(aes(x=TimeBetweenScans,y=Score, group=study_id, color=Time, shape=Groups))+geom_point(size=3)+geom_line(color="Black", linetype="dotted")+labs(title = "Oulu Score vs Time",y="Oulu Score",x="Time from Post-Op Scan to Follow Up Scan", color="Follow-up Scan")
```

I was asked to get the "average" score at different timeframes.  I.e. the average score at 1 year followup (TimeBetweenScans = "365"), 2 years, 3 years, and 4 years.

So for instance, eyeballing it, you'd take all the dotted lines that cross this red line I drew at the 1 year mark, figure out where they were in the Y axis when they crossed that line, and average their "score".
[image]

If I had rows that contained '365' in the "TimeBetweenScans" column, I'd write something like:

```
test%>%filter(TimeBetweenScans=="365")%>%summarise(MeanScore=mean(Score))
```

That code would select only the data right at the year mark and average the y axis score for me.  But since 365 isn't actually ever in a row, and it only exists when those dotted lines cross it, I need to extrapolate what it WOULD be for that person at '365'.

Does that make sense?

If so, how can I do it?

Comment: `test%>%group_by(Time)%>%summarise(TimeBetweenScans=mean(TimeBetweenScans, na.rm = TRUE))`?

Comment: @Onyambu  I don't believe that is what I was thinking.  That seems to get the average days at occurence 1,2,3,4,or 5 (those numbers stand for what # visit it was).   In other words that returns avg 236 days at time 1.  Instead of that I'd like to standardise it at 365 days and return an average of "score = 4.3" or whatever it is.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Not at all. What exactly do you mean by standardize in this case, ie how do you want to transform 236  into 4.3?

Comment: @Onyambu  Sorry for the confusion.   So the 236 has almost nothing to do with the 4.3.  What I mean is that we can effectively ignore the "Time" column.  That "Time" column should be renamed "visit #" or something and has little to do with what I'm asking right now (I should have left it out of this question).  What I do want to know now is at 365 on the x axis ("TimeBetweenScans" column) what average "Score" would we have (from the "Score" column)?  Why I'm having trouble figuring that out is because no rows actually have 365 in the "TimeBetweenScans" column.   I'll edit question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea.
I filtered the nearest days around the desired time (`year_in_days`) for each `study_id`. Then I calculated a regression line between these points and predicted the `Score` for the `year_in_days`. In a last step I calculated the mean over all predictions.

You might get a lot of warnings while filtering because a lot `study_id` groups won't have any value - just NA.

**Code**

```
# Time you are looking for
year_in_days = 100

test %>% 
  group_by(study_id) %>% 
  group_modify(~{
    .x %>% 
      # filter inside each group the nearest time to year_in_days (lower and upper)
      filter((TimeBetweenScans %in% min(TimeBetweenScans[TimeBetweenScans > year_in_days], na.rm = T)) |
               (TimeBetweenScans %in% max(TimeBetweenScans[TimeBetweenScans < year_in_days], na.rm = T))) %>%
      # filter groups with two meassurments and values for Score
      filter(n() == 2 &
               !is.na(Score)) 
    }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(study_id) %>%
  group_modify(~{
    # for each group predict the value at year "year_in_days"
    broom::tidy(predict(lm(Score ~ TimeBetweenScans, .x), data.frame(TimeBetweenScans = c(year_in_days))))
  }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
# calculate mean score over all predictions
  summarise(mean(x))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `mean(x)`
      <dbl>
1      1.14
```